# Getting "ORA-02047 cannot join the distributed transaction in progress" errors since turning on Tomcat connection pooling

Tags: oracle, tomcat, db2, odbc, connection-pooling

Since turning on Tomcat's connection pooling using org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory connections I'm periodically getting ORA-02047 errors when inserting into DB2 databases over ODBC.  I have tried with and without commit statements in the SQL command, and have also enabled defaultAutoCommit="true" in Tomcat's connection's properties in context.xml.  Anyone have any experience with this?

We're using Oracle's DG4ODBC with iSeries Access for Linux ODBC Driver, connecting to an iSeries AS400.

Comment: Not enough detail in question. Which Db2-driver version are you using? Which Db2-server platform (Z/OS, i-series, unix/windows?)

Comment: Sorry - we're using Oracle's DG4ODBC with iSeries Access for Linux ODBC Driver, connecting to an iSeries AS400.

Comment: *version* facts still missing for all components.

Comment: My guess is improper resource management. Is every connection-fetch in a `try/catch/finally` block with a connection-close in the `finally` section?